# ffmpeg - preserve time base and pts of all frames during transcode

Tags: ffmpeg

Context:

I have an application that produces mp4s with HEVC encoding.  I want to convert them to AVC for use in browser-based displaying. A very crucial part of how I want to use this is to preserve exact PTS times, as this is how we correlate the frames to other data streams not included in the video.

Question:

How do I make ffmpeg preserve this information across the transcode?  All the obvious flags seem to have no effect and ffmpeg just does whatever it wants.

```
$ ffprobe -show_streams original.mp4 2>/dev/null | grep time_base
codec_time_base=16666667/500000000
time_base=1/1000
```

Here is my convert command:

```
$ ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -copyts -copytb 0 test.mp4
```

And its result:

```
$ ffprobe -show_streams test.mp4 2>/dev/null | grep time_base
codec_time_base=1/60
time_base=1/15360
```

I would expect the time_bases to match.  The PTS of the frames also don't match when doing `ffprobe -show_frames`

EDIT:
@Gyan suggested using -video_track_timescale, but that didn't get the exact behavior I was looking for:

```
$ sdiff <(ffprobe -show_frames test.mp4  | grep pkt_pts_time) <(ffprobe -show_frames original.mp4 | grep pkt_pts_time)
pkt_pts_time=0.000000                           pkt_pts_time=0.000000
pkt_pts_time=0.033000                           pkt_pts_time=0.033000
pkt_pts_time=0.067000                         | pkt_pts_time=0.066000
pkt_pts_time=0.100000                           pkt_pts_time=0.100000
pkt_pts_time=0.133000                           pkt_pts_time=0.133000
pkt_pts_time=0.167000                         | pkt_pts_time=0.166000
pkt_pts_time=0.200000                           pkt_pts_time=0.200000
pkt_pts_time=0.233000                           pkt_pts_time=0.233000
pkt_pts_time=0.267000                         | pkt_pts_time=0.266000
pkt_pts_time=0.300000                           pkt_pts_time=0.300000
pkt_pts_time=0.333000                           pkt_pts_time=0.333000
pkt_pts_time=0.367000                         | pkt_pts_time=0.366000
pkt_pts_time=0.400000                           pkt_pts_time=0.400000
pkt_pts_time=0.433000                           pkt_pts_time=0.433000
pkt_pts_time=0.467000                           pkt_pts_time=0.467000
pkt_pts_time=0.500000                           pkt_pts_time=0.500000
pkt_pts_time=0.533000                         | pkt_pts_time=0.532000
pkt_pts_time=0.567000                         | pkt_pts_time=0.565000
pkt_pts_time=0.600000                         | pkt_pts_time=0.598000
pkt_pts_time=0.633000                         | pkt_pts_time=0.631000
pkt_pts_time=0.667000                         | pkt_pts_time=0.665000
pkt_pts_time=0.700000                         | pkt_pts_time=0.698000
...
```

Comment: copytb is a boolean, not a mapping. Since the output is MP4, just set `-video_track_timescale X` where X is the input stream TB.

Comment: According to ffmpeg, copytb is not a boolean.

Comment: When I use -video_track_timescale 1000  (thank you for that) it gets closer to matching, but the pkt_pts_times still don't match in all cases

Comment: Add `-vsync 0`.

Comment: Also does not work; the pts times of the converted video are still different

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: I'd prefer not too since it's a surveillance video of myself.  Is there some other form of metadata examination I can perform to generate more information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229786/discussion-between-jdizzle-and-gyan).

Comment: Can you generate a shareable input that shows the same behaviour?

Comment: Here's a dropbox link to the video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/est0t49fufkjvw5/original.mp4

Comment: Had a chance to take a look, @gyan?

Comment: Will take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to set 3 parameters to obtain identical timestamps: `-vsync 0` to avoid frame duplication and timebase adjustment, `-enc_time_base -1` to avoid timebase adjustment at the encoder layer, and `-video_track_timescale` with the inverse of the source timebase.

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vsync 0 -enc_time_base -1 -video_track_timescale 1000 test.mp4
```

Note that with default encoding parameters, B-frames are turned on for the default encoder (libx264 for MP4) and so the frames will be stored in decoding order which is not the same as presentation order. Add `-bf 0` to switch this off.

Comment: Thanks you!  When testing I found I could also omit the `-video_track_timescale 1000` arugment.  Just `-vsync 0` and `-enc_time_base -1` are enough.

Comment: That's not safe for your purposes. The MP4 muxer will upgrade the timescale to a value over 10,000 if the source is lower. Depending on the ratio between the input and output timescales, the rounding can change some timestamps.